# Python glob.glob(): find exact match on a portion of the file name

Tags: python, pattern-matching, glob

I would like to use `glob` to get all the csv files that have a certain string inside the file name. The string only appears in the middle of the file name. For instance, I would like to extract all csv files that have `SI--Exp1` inside the filename, which could look something like `03152018-User1-SI--Exp1-trial14.csv`. Here's what I have so far:

```
import glob
path =r'C:\YourFolder' #path to folder with .csv files
all = glob.glob(path+"/*'[SI--Exp1]'*.csv")
```

which I received an error message of `bad character range 3--`. It said from the documentation that square brackets put inside quotation marks help find the literal match. Any advice?

Comment: They add possible literal matches, but the symbols are still regex syntax and should be escaped, `\-\-` should fix the bad range problem. Also I've never seen square brackets inside quotation as a regex syntax so I'm not sure about if that is exactly like that.

Comment: What exactly do you want to match, everything that ends with `SI--Exp1.csv` ??

Comment: I want every file that has `SI--Exp1` in it, not necessarily at the end.

Comment: Every .csv file I imagine. `.*?SI--Exp1.*?\.csv` should take care of that, matches every string that has `SI--Exp1` and ends with `.csv`

You can try what it would match or wouldn't [here](https://regex101.com/r/AJ89zD/1)

Comment: When I run `all = glob.glob(path+'/*?SI--Exp1.*?\.csv')`, python ran without an error, but found no match. I originally had the code `#all = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")` to incorporate all csv files, but I only wanted a subset of them.

Comment: Okay. I read about glob.glob and apparently it doesn't take python regex rather `shell-style`. So `path+'/*SI--Exp1*.csv'` this should fix it

Answer (score 3):

Apparently the use of quotation marks was unnecessary to find filenames that have a certain string anywhere in the filename. Here's the solution:

```
import glob
path =r'C:\YourFolder' #path to folder with .csv files
all = glob.glob(path+'/*SI--Exp1*.csv')
```

Comment: Can you please mark this as the solution if it answered the question above?